# How do I adjust same position and size?

Tags: html, css, slider, position, size

How do I adjust those two buttons same position and size? I'm trying to create shopify store but don't know how to add the additional button to the slider
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF6Ij.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not add answers to your question with content that is relevant to the question. Instead, edit your question and then add the content to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `align-items:center` on parent div using flexbox.

```
.parent{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```